# Spiral enlargement

Tags: complex-numbers

Say you have the points $A$, $B$ and $C$ in an argand diagram and it is given that $AC=sAB$, where $s \in \mathbb{R}$, and angle $BAC = \theta$. Am I right in thinking that $AC$ is a spiral enlargement of $AB$? so $$AC = se^{\theta i}AB$$
Then if $A$ and $B$ are known, can $C$ be calculated by finding $AC$, then doing $OA+AC$?

Comment: This is confusing, you've suggested that $AC$ and $AB$ are lengths, then you want them to be complex (points?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved as follows: given points $A$ and $B$ on the complex plane, and a point $C$ that is to be determined, subject to the conditions that $AC=sAB$ and that the angle between $AB$ and $AC$, call it $\theta$, is known.

Let us define

$$
z_1=B-A\\
z_2=C-A
$$

From the vector and scalar product of complex 'vectors,' we know that

$$
z_1z_2^*+z_1^*z_2=2|z_1||z_2|\cos\theta\\
z_1z_2^*-z_1^*z_2=i2|z_1||z_2|\sin\theta
$$

Adding these together we get

$$
z_1z_2^*=|z_1||z_2|e^{i\theta}\\
z_2=\frac{|z_1||z_2|e^{-i\theta}}{z_1^*}
$$

or

$$
C=A+\frac{s(AB)^2e^{-i\theta}}{z_1^*}
$$

I have verified this result numerically for random values of $A,B,s,\theta$.